# Kubeflow - Cannot load dashboard menu link

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I'm using `microk8s` on an Unbuntu 20.04 LTS server hosted in AWS (EC2). I want to install `kubeflow` in order to setup a pipeline for machine learning jobs. I followed this official installation guide: https://ubuntu.com/ai/install-kubeflow

Everything worked fine and I am also able to access the kubeflow dashboard, however, the problem is that most of the menu points are missing and I get the following error when opening the dashboard: "Cannot load dashboard menu link".

I did a lot of research and tried many different options (like intalling kubeflow on top of microk8s using juju), but I always get the same error and I ran out of options.

What could be the reason for that and how can I fix that?

Comment: General remark: This error usually appears if centraldashboard pod of Kubeflow is not able to find or successfully parse configmap `centraldashboard-config`. See https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/39bd199d65dc89ef8e2534d97247c5d71899309a/components/centraldashboard/app/api.ts#L78 (KF v1.6.0).   
Make sure that the `links` data of this configmap does not contain any syntax errors and such.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution, it is described here: https://github.com/canonical/bundle-kubeflow/issues/344#issuecomment-827936799

This fixed the issue for me.